# Really fancy plots like in high quality text books

Tags: plotting

Are there online resources (or paper books) that teaches how to make really fancy plots in Mathematica, plots you mostly see in high quality textbooks? I can do the 'default/basic' ones but they are often quite "raw" and not as fine-tuned as I want them. I'm sure there are loads of parameters and tricks that Mathematica can use to produce fine plots.

As an example. Let's say f(x,y) is a surface in R^3 but not on a normal square xy definition area, but instead on a more complex area, like a polygon. How do I plot such a surface with given constraints in the xy-plane?

Thanks in advance for all help and hints.

Comment: I have used *Mathematica* to make several hundred figures (many "really fancy") in my best-selling textbook, ***Pattern classification*** (2nd ed.), and they are extremely clean and polished—far better than other plotting packages.  Actually, I think your question is about plotting over a polygon, which is done using `Plot3D` and `RegionFunction`.

Comment: As is, the question is a bit too broad...

Comment: The question has come up in many forms on this site: [search results for "publication quality"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=publication+quality). As it stands, I would agree that it is too broad. Specify a single problem, with code and an MWE, and we can better help you.

Comment: I'm sorry to have incorrectly phrased the question, I didn't want to look like to be lazy and ask one specific problem for a quick solution. I'm new to this site and "m.o.". OK, so here is a typical problem of mine. f(x,y)=xy(x-y) over the area enclosed by lines y1=2x, y2=1-4x, y3=4+x/2.

Comment: @MF92 Thank you for clarifying. At this point, you might be better served by starting a new question focusing on that particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint to accomplish the specific request you made in the question:

```
Plot3D[
  Sin[3 x] Sin[6 y],
  {x, y} \[Element] RegularPolygon[5]
]
```

[image: isometric view]
[image: top-down view]

Comment: I've noticed that using RegularPolygon to specify the domain gives a decidedly non-publication-quality look (note the jagged lines), thus moving the appearance in a direction opposite of what the OP seeks. A much cleaner result can be obtained with, e.g., `Plot3D[Sin[3 x] Sin[6 y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @theorist The OP specifically said: “... not on a normal square xy definition area, but instead on a more complex area, like a polygon”. Consider also that the jagged lines are artifacts of rasterization, and can probably be avoided at sufficiently high resolution.

Comment: Apologizes, you are correct.  Increasing PlotPoints seems to fix the jagged lines.